# Deep copy in evolution simulator creating memory leak

Tags: python, memory-leaks, neural-network, copy, deep-copy

Recently I've been trying to create an evolution simulator in Python using feedforward neural networks. Everything is working fine except the reproduction functions.

At first, when developing reproduction, I simply called a function that created a new animal object with the same, slightly mutated, attributes that its parents had. I did this by for instance writing `parent.weights = child.weights`. I have learned however that this only creates a reference to the parent's weights, and therefore that the child isn't independent to its parent. So, for instance, whenever a child were to mutate its weights, all other animals with referenced weights would change as well, resulting in sudden, similar changes in behaviour in a whole population.

I later discovered Python's `copy` library. To create a child animal now, I copy the parent's whole object using `copy.deepcopy()` and then alter the copied object to create the child. This works for a while but after about an hour of running the program, it is so slow that no progress can be made. I discovered that when a child was born, and a deep copy was made, the program would completely stop, and load for several seconds at a time.

I have no idea what this is due to, but I have a slight suspicion that it might be a memory leak of some sort. My questions to you are:

1. What may be the cause for this?
2. Is there any solution or alternative method to creating copies of 
     objects without referencing?

Here is the relevant copy, simplified:

Calling reproduction function:

```
#asexual reproduction
if self.energy > (((pow(self.sizeRadius, 2) * 3.14 ))):
    self.birthed_kin += 1
    self.energy -= (pow(self.sizeRadius, 2) * 3.14 ) / 2
    self.birth_timer = 0

    self.copy_animal()
```

Reproduction function:

```
def copy_animal(self):

    copied_animal = copy.deepcopy(self)

    copied_animal.age = 0

    copied_animal.birthed_kin = 0
    copied_animal.sizeRadius = mutate_organ(copied_animal.sizeRadius, 1)
    copied_animal.energy = (pow(copied_animal.sizeRadius, 2) * 3.14) / 2
    copied_animal.health = pow(copied_animal.sizeRadius, 2) * 3.14
    copied_animal.pain = 0

    copied_animal.weights = [ 
mutate_neuralnetwork( copied_animal, copied_animal.input_size, copied_animal.hidden_sizes[0], copied_animal.weights[0], copied_animal.mutation_rate), 
mutate_neuralnetwork( copied_animal, copied_animal.hidden_sizes[0], copied_animal.output_size, copied_animal.weights[1], copied_animal.mutation_rate), 
   ]

    living_animals_array.append(copied_animal)
```

Please let me know if I should share any more code or details.

Answer (score 0):

I think what might be happening is that your implementation is recursive and because of this, the GC is never able to release all your previous copies! (Or maybe there's some other reason why the GC cannot release those items)

In evolutionary programming, you often only need to keep a certain number of best-performing 'children' if I remember correctly. You should keep a separate list of these children and push new ones onto the list but also make sure to remove the old ones! Now, also make sure your implementation is not recursive and there's no references to old instances anymore. If you do this correctly, the GC will correctly free up any instances that you are not using and your problems might just go away :)

---

EDIT: After OPs comment:

---

I'm not exactly sure what the `mutate_neuralnetwork` function does. But looking at your code and taking into account the fact that copying becomes increasingly slower it might be that your data structure is recursive. I.e. if `copied_animal` contains a reference to a previous instance which in turn references and even earlier version and then you could imagine that at some point the chain becomes so long that copying it takes a long time. These would be the old references. Make sure you do not have a recursive data structure OR sometimes setting the variables to None can help the GC determine they are not needed anymore.

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick response! :) I have a working genetic algorithm that does this, and I also have information on the length of the different arrays. That isn't the problem I think. However, the thing you mentioned about Being careful and making sure that there are no references to old instances anymore could definitely be the case! Do you have any idea how one of these checks could be done to find the error?

Comment: Another question, if it is the case that there are old references, wouldn't that just slow the program down? In my case, the program only stops when a new copy is being made. This leads me to think that maybe creating a copy of a copy is inefficient?